# Require password not able to change time delay , it is greyed out

Tags: macos, password, system-settings

Why is the checkbox in the second line greyed out ?

[image]

Comment: did you check the power saver settings as well as screen saver settings for a case when screensaver never comes up ?

Comment: Yes I did, but it seems  none of that is an issue.